# Getting correct counts from Pandas Groupby

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a Pandas DataFrame with the following:

```
Name   | Attended
Smith  | Y
Smith  | Y
Smith  | N
Adams  | N
Adams  | Y
Morgan | Y
Morgan | Y
```

and I'd like to count the number of Y's and Ns for each Name.
so the output would be:

```
Name  | Attended| Count
Smith | Y       | 2
      | N       | 1
Adams | Y       | 1
      | N       | 1
Morgan| Y       | 3
      | N       | 0
```

I tried `df.groupby(["Name","Attended"]).count()` and variations of it, but for some reason I don't get the right output. I get either the Name and simply the count (Smith 3, Adam 2, Morgan 3) or the same dataframe again. Help! Am I grouping by incorrectly? I looked for awhile over similar questions and my code matches with the answers there.

I'm using Python 3 and jupyter notebook.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Point out a column to `count` with

```
df.groupby(["Name ","Attended"])["Attended"].count().to_frame(name='Count')
Out[842]: 
                   Count
Name     Attended       
Adams    N             1
         Y             1
Morgan   Y             2
Smith    N             1
         Y             2
```

Comment: Thanks! Follow up question: I'd also like to do a sum aggregation on another column, also grouped by Name and Attended. Is there a way to do both in one go? 
I.e. if I had a column called "Points", and I also wanted to sum up the points for each person -> for each Y and for each N.

Comment: @L.Chu you can check `agg`https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html

Answer (score 2):

Or get the size of each group

```
df = df.groupby(['Name', 'Attended']).size().to_frame(name = 'Count')


                Count
Name    Attended    
Adams   N       1
        Y       1
Morgan  Y       2
Smith   N       1
        Y       2
```